# How to create an AES-encrypted PKCS #8 file?

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rsa, pkcs#8

I'm trying to encrypt an RSA private key with an AES key to create a PKCS #8 file, using standard Java libraries.

When I run the example code (using Java 7), below, I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: unrecognized 
algorithm name: AES
    at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.get(AlgorithmId.java:440)
    at javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:178)
    at Example.main(Example.java:30)
```

[Digging into the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/x509/AlgorithmId.java#429) of `sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId`, this exception suggests it was unable to map `"AES"` to a suitable OID.

I tried replacing `"AES"` with `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"`, but that causes the `AlgorithmParameters.getInstance()` call to fail with "*AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding AlgorithmParameters not available*".

I also tried declaring the algorithm explicitlty as [2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.2](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.2.html), but that also fails with an "*AlgorithmParameters not available*" error.

As [noted in the comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210511/how-to-create-an-aes-encrypted-pkcs-8-file#comment44901677_28210511), this error does not occur in Java 8.

#### Example Code

```
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
generator.initialize(1024);
KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
SecretKey zmkKey = new SecretKeySpec(new byte[16], "AES");

Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
c.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, zmkKey, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
byte[] encryptedPrivateKey = c.wrap(keyPair.getPrivate());

AlgorithmParameters algorithmParameters = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("AES");
algorithmParameters.init(new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));

new EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo(algorithmParameters, encryptedPrivateKey); // line 30
```

Comment: Example code works with `AlgorithmParameters algorithmParameters = AlgorithmParameters.getInstance("AES")` under JDK 8u31

Comment: Also, are you sure about `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE`? Shouldn't you use `Cipher.WRAP_MODE` to encrypt keys?

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Yes, you are quite correct! So it seems to be a problem with Java 7 at least. And yes, `WRAP_MODE` is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Compare http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/70e3553d9d6e/src/share/classes/sun/security/x509/AlgorithmId.java around L507 and http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/c46daef6edb5/src/share/classes/sun/security/x509/AlgorithmId.java around L507 too. Seems like it was simply missing from Java 7, even while http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#AlgorithmParameters says that AES is supported for `AlgorithmParameters`.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Seems like you've uncovered the root cause, thank you. It didn't occur to me to check the Standard Names document. It may be helpful to others if you summarise your findings in an answer? I'd be happy to then accept that.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Further testing has shown that in Java 8, the OID inserted into the PKCS #8 file is [`2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1`](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.html) (AES) rather than [`2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.2`](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.2.html) (id-aes128-CBC). That caused my target system to reject the file. So BouncyCastle seems to remain the only viable option, even with Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

For the time being, I've resorted to using BouncyCastle. Below is the code that produces a PEM-encoded, AES-encrypted PKCS #8 object.

I would still be interested if there's a solution that uses just standard JDK libraries (and works prior to Java 8).

```
final byte[] iv = new byte[16]; // random would be better

OutputEncryptor encryptor = new OutputEncryptor() {
    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream(OutputStream encOut) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, zmkKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
            return new CipherOutputStream(encOut, cipher);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public GenericKey getKey() {
        return new JceGenericKey(getAlgorithmIdentifier(), zmkKey);
    }

    @Override
    public AlgorithmIdentifier getAlgorithmIdentifier() {
        return new AlgorithmIdentifier(
                NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_aes128_CBC,
                // AES CBC mode requires an IV, specified as an octet string
                new DEROctetString(iv));
    }
};

PKCS8Generator pkcs8Generator = new JcaPKCS8Generator(keyPair.getPrivate(), encryptor);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
try (PemWriter writer = new PemWriter(sw)) {
    writer.writeObject(pkcs8Generator);
}

String pemPKCS8 = sw.toString();
```